# Simple random walk and sudden drift, how to detect the change?

Tags: change-point, online-algorithms

I have got the following question relating to random walks. I would like to determine the moment when a random walk changes from being a simple random walk to start to drift at certain time. This sort of scenario could happen when temperatures start to rise or sea levels droppping. The idea is to detect that change as soon as possible. Clearly if the system is left to drift for a long time, it is fairly obvious it has changed from a given initial level (given by the simple random walk at the start), but I would like to know if it is possible to detect that change very quickly after it happens. What sort of analysis would be needed? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Many thanks!!

Michael and whuber, I really appreciate your comments. My initial question was in fact related to Quality Control, as I am trying to model a CUSUM as a Random Walk: When the system is in-control, I see it as a simple random walk, when it starts to drift and eventually goes out-of-control, I see it as a drifting random walk. Thus my question as to how (and critically, how quickly) to detect this change from stationary to drifting within random walks. I can see it is not easy to detect the drift, specially when the drift is small due to the stochastic nature of the system. But I think the ARIMA idea will help me, I had not looked at this theory before and thank you for this advice. Mili.

Comment: Detecting a drift in a random walk is not easy.

Comment: That's right, @Michael: but are you then implicitly agreeing that temperature or sea level series truly are "random walks"? I think the problem here is that the OP is using "random walk" in a nontechnical sense and perhaps really only means "stationary" or "nontrending."  Mili, [is that the case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)?

Comment: @whuber I am just going by the OPs premise that it is a random walk.  If mili intended something else i have no idea.  If mili means that the process starts out stationary and then starts drifting then maybe fitting a stationary ARMA model would be a good approach and the drift could be detected in the residuals.  The drift could also be interpreted as an intervention and modeled as a change in the series with an addition of a linear component. An automated program like AUTOBOX could fit the model and identify the time of the intervention.

Comment: Mili, you will find several dozen closely related--and possibly helpful--threads by clicking on the [tag:change-point] tag.  Keywords for a general search of literature and software are "changepoint" (which refers to a sudden change) and "online" (which, in statistics, often refers to applying procedures to a steady stream of data). A related search term would be "quality control" and associated technical words such as "cusum" and "control chart."

Comment: Michael, Whuber, How much of a "history" of data is needed to be able to use the AUTOBOX or ARIMA models suggested?

Comment: @Michael, You are absolutely correct in your assessment of AUTOBOX's approach. The amount of "history" that is needed is strictly dependent on the ratio of signal to noise. The higher the ratio the lesser the required history. There is another question when identifying level shifts and local time trends and  that deals with the question "how many values are needed in the new group" before it is classified as a new group. This requires the user to quantify the opportunity cost of alternative conclusions and to set this value accordingly.

Comment: For testing that a process is going out of control CUSUM charts are commonly used but if you are dealing with a change in a general ARMA model I would prefer to try the intervention identification approach. As IrishStat mentioned this involves some specifications on the part of the users.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting a drift in a random walk is a lot harder than you make it out to be. Random walks are nonstationary sequences that can have long excursions in one direction or another. So they appear to drift even without any change in the process. Since the random walk fits an ARIMA first difference model, you could apply the model to the data and look to see where the residuals seem to go astray.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am not familiar with ARIMA but will look into it. Is the idea behind ARIMA to look at the residuals once the difference of original data with random noise is calculated?

Comment: ARIMA is a model structure.  It stands for autoregressive integrated moving average process.  This modle include differening the series "the I part"  A difference would be done by constructing Y(t)=X(t)- X(t-1).  First differencing removes linear trends and drifting that comes about in a random walk.  The AR terms simply provide a regression of the time seires on itself at earlier times.  The moving average component creates correaltion by creating a linear combination of random noise terms.  Each AR and MA term has a coeffocoent associated with it.

Comment: These coefficients are estimated to fit the time series as best as you can in terms of mean square error.  There are restrictions on the AR coefficients for the series to be stationary.